# Square root implementations

Tags: c#, interview-questions, mathematics, comparative-review

The question was:

> Write a function that calculates the root of a given number.

- Answer A = I wrote it for integers. just run up to half of the number
- Answer B+C = are for double, using Newton's law.

I just implemented [this](http://stevekrenzel.com/articles/newtons-law) in C#.

They all work and were tested.Please comment me about anything from not well written code, complexity, style, or give a better solution.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    public class FindSquareRoot
    {
        public FindSquareRoot()
        {
            int numberToFind = 49;
            int res = SquareRoot(numberToFind);
            Console.WriteLine(res);

            double doubleNumberToFind = 157.0;
            double resDouble = SquareRoot(doubleNumberToFind);
            Console.WriteLine(resDouble);
            resDouble = SquareRootBetter(doubleNumberToFind);
            Console.WriteLine(resDouble);
        }

        public int SquareRoot(int number)
        {
            int half = number / 2;
            int counter = 0;
            while (counter < half)
            {
                if (Math.Pow(counter, 2.0) == number)
                {
                    return counter;
                }
                counter++;
            }
            return half;
        }

        public double SquareRoot(double number)
        {
            double precision = 10e-8;
            double low = 0.0;
            double high = 0.0;
            double prev = 0.0;
            double mid = number / 2.0;

            while(Math.Abs(mid - prev) > precision )
            {
                if(Math.Pow(mid,2) > number)
                {
                    high = mid;
                }else
                {
                    low = mid;
                }
                prev = mid;
                mid = (low+high)/ 2.0;
            }
            return mid;
        }
        public double SquareRootBetter(double number)
        { 
            double precision = 10e-8;
            double prev = 0.0;
            double mid = number;
            while(Math.Abs(mid - prev ) > precision)
            {
                prev = mid;
                mid = (mid +(number/ mid))/2.0;
            }
            return mid;
        }    
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- `SquareRoot(int)`

  - returns `half` if the integer is not a perfect square. A very dubious decision. I'd consider returning a best integer approximation, or throwing an exception.
  - uses a linear search. A binary search would be quite faster. A Newton-Raphson (yes it works with integers) would be even factor.
- An error approximation is better done as `Math.abs(number - Math.pow(candidate_square_root, 2))`

Answer (score 5):

`SquareRoot(int)` doesn't seem to work for anything except perfect squares. Here are some examples:

> ```
>  x    SquareRoot(x)  SquareRoot(x)^2
> -------------------------------------
>  8               4               16
> 10               5               25
> 40              20              400
> ```

If your method is not intended to work with non-perfect squares, it would be a very good idea to document this.

Answer (score 3):

**Naming**

Based on the [naming guidlines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229002.aspx) methodnames should be made out of verbs or verb phrases. So e.g `SquareRoot` should become `FindSquareRoot`

Class names should be made out of nouns or noun phrases. So e.g `FindSquareRoot` should become `SquareRootCalculator`.

**Constructor**

The constructor of an object has the purpose to **construct** the object, hence the name. You shouldn't use the constructor to do the work.

You should better write tests for testing the methods instead of doing this in the constructor.

**Algorithm**

If you can use `Math.Pow()` as you already do, you can simplify this extremely by just returning `Math.Pow(input, 0.5)`.

**General**

As the methods don't depend on any state of the object, you should declare them `static` and because all methods should be `static`, the class itself should be `static` too.

Comment: Mathematical functions generally don't use a prefix like `Find`.